# How to type cast, from "string" which is originally number to number

Tags: typescript

```
 //I am working on this assignment
objToSendServer.input1 = obj.input1

//type definitions are:

class obj {
    input1: number;
}

class objToSendServer{
    input1: number
}

// if I do this assignment that value of obj.input1 is "1"
// which cause of problem on server side 
// which is web api odata, patch method that expects type of int
objToSendServer.input1 = obj.input1;  

// if I try cast as below, error message is:
//Argument of type 'number' is not assingable of parameter of type 'string'
objToSendServer.input1 = parseFloat(obj.input1); 

//My work around is:
objToSendServer.input1 = parseFloat(obj.input1.toString());
```

I suppose that type cast would be done automatically which is not case here.

So my question is there better approach to this type of assignment

Also if obj.input1 is null this workaround fails.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
```

Then I should check if `obj.input1` is null or not

Note: I edited the title which was `Is there "automatic" type cast in typescript` to express issue more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code handles non-numbers, empty strings, undefined variables, null variables, and even numbers. It supplies a default value of 0 for all the "error" cases.

```
objToSendServer.input1 = +obj.input1 || 0;
```

Here is a simplified demo. It shows four possible inputs (that are either a string or a number) and then uses [slacker parsing](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201402/Blog/Slacker-Parsing-In-JavaScript/) to get a value.

```
var a: string | number = "1";

var b: string | number = 2;

var c: string | number;

var d: string | number = "A";

var w: number = +a || 0;
alert(w); // 1

var x: number = +b || 0;
alert(x); // 2

var y: number = +c || 0;
alert(y); // 0

// It even infers the `number` type:
var z = +d || 0;
alert(z); // 0
```

If you want to preserve `null` values, you would have to add a special case for that.

```
var n = (a === null) ? a : +a || 0;
```

Remember that `null` is distinct from `undefined`, so you will get `0` for `undefined`.

If you want only the parsed number, or `null` (i.e. `null` is the default for any value that fails the parse):

```
var n = +a || null;
```

Comment: I am telling about in my question `I should check if obj.input1 is null or not`. Is there a way better than ` if obj.input1 is null ` according to your answer.

Comment: The example I have supplied checks for nulls already. The expression `variable || 0` will return `0` if `variable` is null.

Comment: But the if input is null the result remain null as well not 0

Comment: I have added some additional options you can choose from depending on what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but you should solve this issue at the source by ensuring that the value in `obj.input1` is always a `number` in the first place.

```
obj.input1 = (typeof val === "string") ? parseFloat(val) : val;
```

Note: `val` being, whatever you're assigning to `obj.input1`.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak doing `typeof val === "string"` will [typeguard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx) the type of `val` to `string` so `.toString()` would be unnecessary.

Comment: Could you complete `...` then I could try in my programme your solution

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak i don't know how `obj.input1` is being assigned to in your code. My main point is that when you assign to `obj.input1`, you should ensure the value being assigned is a string and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're coming from a wrong assumption and trying to make the language work from there.

There is no "casting" to be done automatically since `parseFloat()` accepts strings only and you have to be more clear about how you want to convert values. You have a property of type `number`, which in your code example may have a `string`, in which case you want to do a different thing. So it's more than casting.

Setting a `string` value to a `number` would have errors of its own, but let's ignore that for now.

First, if you may have different types on the same property, you should use union types:

```
class obj {
    input1: number|string;
}
```

And then your code should interpret it by checking the type, like David Sherret answered:

```
objToSendServer.input1 = typeof obj.input1 === 'string' ? parseFloat(obj.input1) : obj.input1;
```

TypeScript will correctly interpret the type check conditional and provide you with type checking for each case.

Comment: String is coming from ng-model of angularjs from interface. When value assigned it is  string instead of number. so `input1: number|string;` is a desirable definition.I just should handle type cast

Answer (score 0):

> Is there “automatic” type cast in typescript

No. There is *type compatiblity* and *structural typing*.

> // if I try cast as below, error message is:
>   //Argument of type 'number' is not assingable of parameter of type 'string'

The issue is that `parseFloat` accepts only a `string` and you are passing it a `number`. If `obj.input1` is a number **You do not need to do a `parseFloat` on it**.

Comment: String is coming from ng-model of angularjs from interface. When value assigned it is  string instead of number